# Angular 2 form validation: fields inside components

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<form>
   <my-component></my-component>
</form>
```

"my-component" in it's template has an "input" element.

How can I make my "form" to be aware of that field inside the component?
I use template-driven form approach and I would like it to stay this way.
The input has the "name" and "ngModel" set.

Comment: You'll have to bind the value into and out of the component.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `FormGroup` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html).

- Create a `FormGroup` object in your parent component.
- Use 2 way binding to pass this `FormGroup` to your `my-component`.
- Inside your `my-component`, add your input to the `FormGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Form, either template-driven or model-driven (reactive), doesn't look into the component's template. It will communicate with the child components only if they implement **ControlValueAccessor** interface.

More details can be found in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286138/324224